# ActiveRecord validation error: saying field is blank even though it isn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

When I create try to create a new ActiveRecord I get the following error:

```
Failure/Error: @gallery = Gallery.create!(gallery_picture: ["test"], GeneralInfo_id: 1, gallery_title: "test", gallery_description: "test")
     
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Gallery picture can't be blank
```

This is the schema for the galleries table:

```
create_table "galleries", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "gallery_title"
    t.text "gallery_description"
    t.string "gallery_picture", array: true
    t.float "gallery_totalRate"
    t.integer "gallery_totalRator"
    t.integer "GeneralInfo_id"
    t.string "test_picture", array: true
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "gallery"
    t.text "comments", default: [], array: true
  end
```

And here is my Gallery Model:

```
class Gallery < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :general_info, optional: true
    has_many :reviews
    has_many :gallery_taggings, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :tagged_users, through: :gallery_taggings, source: :general_info

    validates_presence_of :gallery_title
    validates_presence_of :gallery_description
    validates_presence_of :gallery_picture
    validates_presence_of :GeneralInfo_id
    mount_uploaders :gallery_picture, GalleryUploader

    mount_uploaders :test_picture, GalleryUploader
    has_many :comments

end
```

I don't understand why this error is being raised since the gallery_picture field is not blank. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please add your complete gallery model

Comment: I added it above.

Comment: `mount_uploaders :gallery_picture, GalleryUploader` is trying to load a file from the gallery_picture field and will null it out when it fails.  FYI gallery_picture should NOT be an array, and you need to use an actual file

Comment: So, should I just put in a string containing a file path?

Comment: Your schema is very wonky. Drop the table prefixes (`gallery_`) and make sure the columns are consistently using `snake_case` and not an ungodly mix of naming schemes. Also why is `gallery_picture` an array column? If you intend to store multiple pictures in a gallery do yourself a favor and create a separate table. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#convention-over-configuration-in-active-record